# i am getting SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

Tags: jquery

Here is my code having a form using ajax and jquery.  Whenever I refresh the page I get this error  in my inspect element area at console tab:

> SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Ajax Test</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('form[id=test_form]').submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var inp = $("#test_input").val();
                var sub = $("#test_submit").val();
                $(".test_msg").load("hello_ajax.php", {
                    inp: inp,
                    sub: sub
                });
            });
        });
        </script>



</head>
<body>
    <h2>Testing Ajax</h2>
    <form id="test_form" action="hello_ajax.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" id="test_input" name="tst_input">
        <button type="submit" id="test_submit" name="tst_submit">Submit</button>
        <p class="test_msg"></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this line is the problem

```
$('form[id=test_form]').submit(function (event) {
```

Try using:

```
$('#test_form').submit(function (event) {
```

and...

```
var sub = $("#test_submit").val();
```

The submit button has no value

```
<button type="submit" id="test_submit" name="tst_submit">Submit</button>
```